# How to convert date string into format "17 Nov 2010"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have the date that is in format **2010-11-17**.This is of the form **NSString**.

I want to convert this **NSString date** into format **17 Nov 2010** and display in a label

This date is just not the current date but may even be the older dates.

So I cant use the [NSDate date] instance to get the date.

I tried using **NSDateFormatter** with the method **dateFromString**.

But it gives me a **null** value.

Here is the code snippet

```
NSString *dates  = @”2010-11-16”;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];
NSDate *dates1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dates];
NSString *dates2 = [dateFormatter stringForObjectValue:dates1];
NSLog(@"dates : %@",dates);
NSLog(@"Dates 2 :  %@",dates2);
[dateLabel setText:dates2];
NSLog(@"Formatted Date is : %@",dateLabel.text);
```

What should be done?

Please Help and suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
NSDateFormatter *formater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formater setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *date2 = [formater dateFromString:@"2010-11-17"];
[formater setDateFormat:@"d MMM yyyy"];
NSString *result = [formater stringFromDate:date2];
NSLog(@"RESULT %@",result);
```

I got the result.Correct me if this approach is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some formats for who desire to know!!

```
 12:16:45 PM on January 01, 2000   --> hh:mm:ss a 'on' MMMM dd, yyyy
 Wednesday, Sep 12, 2018           --> EEEE, MMM d, yyyy--
 09/12/2018                        --> MM/dd/yyyy--
 09-12-2018 14:11                  --> MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm--
 Sep 12, 2:11 PM                   --> MMM d, h:mm a--
 September 2018                    --> MMMM yyyy--
 Sep 12, 2018                      --> MMM d, yyyy
 Wed, 12 Sep 2018 14:11:54 +0000   --> E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z
 2018-09-12T14:11:54+0000          --> yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ
 12.09.18                          --> dd.MM.yy
 10:41:02.112                      --> HH:mm:ss.SSS
 12:16:45 PM                       --> hh:mm:ss a
 AM or PM                          --> a
```

Answer (score 0):

[`NSDateFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) uses [date format patterns from UNICODE](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

So for your **17 Nov 2010** date you need something like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"d MMM yyyy"];
NSString *result = [formatter stringForObjectValue:date];
```

Where `date` variable contains the date you'd like to format.

UPDATE: Try changing your code to this:

```
NSString *dates  = @”2010-11-16”;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *dates1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dates];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];
NSString *dates2 = [dateFormatter stringForObjectValue:dates1];
NSLog(@"dates : %@",dates);
NSLog(@"Dates 2 :  %@",dates2);
[dateLabel setText:dates2];
NSLog(@"Formatted Date is : %@",dateLabel.text);
```

Comment: I have tried the code you gave but it still returns null value.

Comment: @PARTH what's giving you a null value?

Comment: the "result" variable in console shows null value.My "date" variable is NSString

Comment: @PARTH: is your date variable non-null?

Comment: Ya my date variable is non null.

Comment: my date variable is : date = @"2010-11-15";

Comment: @PARTH: then that's your problem. `stringForObjectValue` expects a `NSDate` instance, not a `NSString` instance. `@"2010-11-15"` is a `NSString` instance. Do create a `NSDate` object from your `NSString` object and try the code snippet again.

Comment: Still the same. It still gives null value.

Comment: Update your question with the exact code you are using so we'll see if we can help you.

Comment: Updated my answer with a minor change. I didn't know you were using `NSDateFormatter` to do the parsing also. You need to switch the correct format when parsing and outputting.

Comment: @Pablo Somehow it shows but it shows the wrong date. 2010-11-17 gives date as 17 Jan 2010 instead of 17 Nov 2010

Comment: @PARTH: wow, that's weird. Did you try changing the date to see a pattern?

Comment: @Pablo Santa Cruz: Have you found any solution for the "17 Jan 2010" problem?